# CKEditor accessing http content

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor on a secure page. When I open the editor, I get this error in the JavaScript console:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://facweb.cse.msu.edu/cbowen/cse476/lib/interact/?i=20' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ace/1.1.4/noconflict/ace.js'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is there some setting I need to change to ensure it is not trying to access content using http and instead using https (which does work for that site).

Answer (score 1):

You have included some plugin that uses ACE (I guess that it must be some plugin to enhance editing in source mode) and it has hardcoded the path to the library as http instead of https.

So you have to find out which plugin is that and request its author to modify the plugin so it uses // or just always https

Answer (score 1):

ckeditor/plugins/pbckcode/plugin.js -> line 37